# Applying Groupby and aggregation on a set of dynamically selected columns

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a dataframe and need to group the data based on some columns.

Static way:

```
dfMMS_BBMS_pv.columns
['area_type', 'area_name', 'area_code', 'date', 'A_BBMS',
   'A_MMS', 'Others_BBMS', 'Others_MMS', 'B_BBMS',
   'C_BBMS', 'C_MMS', 'T_BBMS', 'V_BBMS',
   'D_BBMS', 'D_MMS']

dfMMS_BBMS_pv=dfMMS_BBMS_pv.groupby(['area_type', 'area_name', 'area_code']).\
agg({'date': lambda x: list((x)) ,'A_MMS': lambda x: 
list(round(x,2)) })
```

Now my question is that how I can make this aggregation dynamic based on a set of columns' names which have a specific pattern:

```
Interested_Cols=dfMMS_BBMS_pv.filter(regex='BBMS|MMS').columns

dfMMS_BBMS_pv=dfMMS_BBMS_pv.groupby(['area_type', 'area_name', 'area_code']).\
agg({'date': lambda x: list((x)) ,[i: lambda x : list(round(x,2)) for i in       
list(Interested_Cols)]
```

To clarify, the date column should be present.

Error I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create final dictionary before aggregation by merge both dicts and pass to [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
d = {**{'date': lambda x: list(x)},
     **{i: lambda x: list(round(x,2)) for i in Interested_Cols}}

dfMMS_BBMS_pv=dfMMS_BBMS_pv.groupby(['area_type', 'area_name', 'area_code']).agg(d)
```

Comment: @Moh-Spark - yes, you are right

Comment: in python 3.9 you can simplify the dictionary merge with the `|` operator: `{'date': lambda x: list(x)} | {i: lambda x: list(round(x,2)) for i in Interested_Cols}`